# Measuring bandwidth from a server - determine capacity of network

Tags: networking, benchmark

I am building a system that will serve video content, and am trying to determine the maximum throughput I can achieve.

I have been using iperf3, and initially, from a separate VM (in the same data-centre), I get great bandwidth (7Gbps). Then I considered that it might just be a within-data-centre bandwidth. I started testing from different data centres, but was quickly constricted by the bandwidth of the test machine. I'm not exceeding 1Gbps.

How can I be certain that I'm measuring *my server's* throughput, and not the test machine's limits? Is there best-practice guidance to do this?

Should I coordinate multiple remote servers, each in different data centres, and then aggregate the results?

Is there a tool or a platform that permits this?

Sorry for the broadness of this question, but even my search attempts have failed on an uncertainty of how to phrase the question.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I spun up a bunch of VM's in a different cloud, and used https://locust.io to coordinate a script that tests the specific pages on my site that I want to test. Not sure it is entirely foolproof, but at least was able to confirm that I am able to send 5Gbps, which puts me at ease.